# what are the best ways to study Gem5 CPU models

Tags: gem5

This is a very generic question. What is the best way to study basic CPU models in gem5 so that i can build my own cpu models using them. DO i need to understand the base models fully. I mean do i need to go through the codes line by line to understand the funcionality of those cpu models in gem5?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but it might help if you explain why you want to create a new CPU model, what is the end goal?

Comment: I actually want to build a cpu models having diversity in its execution such as an instruction would be dynamically configured to consume different amount of clock cycles. Mostly i want mess with the timing of each stage of pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is only to change the timing of different pipeline stages, you can change it in your configuration script, as the cpu models in gem5 have options. You can change instruction latencies, number of functional units, cycles between fetch/decode/execute/...

You could take a look at https://github.com/gem5/gem5/tree/master/configs/common/cores/arm where the authors of these file set some options to change the structure of a cpu core. The core still uses the detailed gem5 out-of-order cpu model, but only the parameters (sizes of structures, latencies between structures ...) are modified.

Using this as an example you could change what you want without having to fully understand the code for the detailed cpu model.